# Are Masters' degrees in Sweden and Denmark free?

Tags: masters, university, sweden, denmark

Information on the internet is not clear, hence my question.

I have read that masters in Denmark and Sweden are free for Europeans. I am from Spain, so I could potentially apply.

My questions:

- is there any contract where the student has to live/work in the country for a certain period before/after studying/applying for the masters?
- If I don’t finish the master, do I have to pay for it?
- It sounds too good to be true… if that’s the case, how come all Europeans don’t go to study to Denmark/Sweden? Why would any British, Italian, etc study outside Denmark/Sweden?

Comment: "how come all Europeans don’t go to study to Denmark/Sweden?" - because university is basically free in some other European countries, as well?

Comment: http://www.mastersportal.eu/articles/405/tuition-fees-at-universities-in-europe-in-2017-overview-and-comparison.html

Comment: A project manager in Google earns around 300K$/year. How come all people don't work in Google?

Comment: The amount of project managers is limited and Google would hire only the top x. Potenially (if they d feel like), all adult european citizens could move to those countries to study. I think cold is one reason and the other being that is not free but really cheap in the rest of europe.

Answer (score 7):

I finished my Master's in Sweden in 2009.  I am from The Netherlands.  Higher education is unconditionally free of charge in Sweden.  There used to be a mandatory student union membership with a fee of around 100 SEK/year (a little over €10) but this was abolished by the Reinfeldt government.  It does not matter whether you finish or whether you stay in the country afterwards.

EU does not permit tuition fee discrimination between native and EU students, so as long as higher education is free for Swedes it is free for EU students.  It is no longer free for non-EU students, who in fact pay some of the highest fees in the world.  I believe EEA students are free of charge as well.

However, you still need to finance your own cost of living, which may not be easy as finding a job without knowing Swedish will be difficult.  The Swedish government only provides grants to Swedish students.

To answer your last question, there are plenty of students from other European countries studying in Sweden.

Comment: The courses are taught in English, I presume?

Comment: Yes, Master's are normally taught in English.  The quality of the English is variable, though.

Comment: Also, finding an apartment to rent in Stockholm is near impossible.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson True, but there are many other universities in Sweden that are pretty good.